# how is "heroku config | grep REDIS" formulated on windows cmd

Tags: windows, git, heroku, cmd, redis

I am watching a tutorial and I am not sure on how the following command is formulated on windows cmd prompt, `heroku config | grep REDIS`.

Error log when executing this on windows cmd:

```
Mickell@DESKTOP-JJ707K1 MINGW64 ~
$ heroku config | grep REDIS
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, the grep alternative is findStr.

heroku config | findStr REDIS